# how do I use jmeter to determine if value1 = x within json payload, does value2 = y?

Tags: json, jmeter

so basically I'm trying to use jmeter to dissect a json payload. I want to look at the payload, determine if one value equals something, and if that value is correct, determine if another value within that "module" is correct. example below:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "foo": [
    {
    "ID": 570,
    "valueX": 1,
    "blah1": 1,
    "ValueY": 10,
    "blah2": "10"
    },
    {
    "ID": 570,
    "valueX": 2,
    "blah1": 1,
    "ValueY": 0,
    "blah2": "0"
    }]
}}
```

so if I wanted to determine if `valueX = 2`, and verify that `valueY = 0`, how would I go about doing that? I'm familiar with using the json path `$.data.foo[0].valueY`, but in this instance, the API returns the values in different orders. so `valueX` might be 1 or 2 depending on `ID`.

any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For JsonPath you could use something like:

```
$.data.foo..[?(@.valueX==2)].ValueY
```

what it does:

- `$.data.foo..` returns all elements inside `foo`
- `[?(@.valueX==2)]` filters those elements, whose `valueX` is 2
- `.ValueY` returns ValueY for the same element.

As for how to do it, there're many ways. Here's the "no frills" one:

1. Under sampler, add Json Extractor like so:

[image]

(create variable `aaa` that contains a result of evaluation of JSON expression)

2. Still under sampler, after Json Extractor, add Response Assertion like so:

[image]

(check if variable `aaa` **Equals** 0, which is the expected value for `ValueY`, according to original question.)

Of course the name of variable (`aaa`) can be changed in both places

The whole fragment looks like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you! that was exactly what I was looking for. I used the JSON 
Path Assertion to use the "Validate against expected value" option within the JSON Path Assertion, so that I could avoid adding another Response Assertion. is this still a valid test method?

also, do you have a preferred resource for learning more about JSON Paths? thank you again for the answer to my problem, you saved me a headache and a half.

Comment: Sure, Json Path assertion is a better method actually, it's not part of standard JMeter, and I didn't know if you have it, hence used the other one.
I find the most helpful way to learn is to try it using this: http://jsonpath.com/
Of course prior to that learning basic syntax helps (there's a link from jsonpath.com to JSONPath expressions explanation). If you know XPath, it helps too, just need to find equivalents.

Comment: excellent answers to everything, thank you again! hopefully I can help share this knowledge with other people in the future thanks to your help.